# Initializing a GLfloat

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opengl

Why can't I do this?

```
#include <gl/gl.h>

GLfloat posX;

 posX=0.0f;
```

Visual Studio says:

> error C4430: missing type specifier -
>   int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int

Comment: Have you #included `<gl/gl.h>` or similar in your source file?

Comment: The code compiles fine with g++. I assume the missing semi-colon on the line `posX=0.0f` is not the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right line?  That error is given when you create a function without a return type.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you have to include glut and let the compiler know where the glut is, since glut is an external library, and then `#include <GL/glut.h>`. I remember this is how I did.

Comment: @PigBen. Not necessarily. The error occurs when a declaration, like a function return or a variable, doesn't specify a known type. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173696%28v=vs.80%29.aspx  I would assume here that the compiler does not know what a GLfloat is because the correct header file hasn't been included.

Comment: Are you getting any other compiler errors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The text

```
 posX=0.0f;
```

is at global scope, so is treated as a declaration, not a statement. Consider:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>

GLfloat posY = 0.0f;

GLfloat posX;
posX = 0.0f;

GLfloat posZ;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    posZ = 0.0f;
    return 0;
}
```

Then posY, posZ compile fine, but posX shows the issue. Note the issue is nothing to do with GL; you'll get it if you replace GLfloat with plain old float.